# How can I show my flutter app to interviewer if I have used an api from other website in my app due to that I can't deploy app on playstore

Tags: flutter, api, deployment

How can I show my flutter app to interviewer if I have used an api from other website in my app due to that  I can't deploy app on playstore. Is there any website where I can deploy my app?

Answer (score 0):

Release  an APK  file and upload it to your server and give him the link to download it and  install it, let him test it then ask him to remove it, you do this for android but the android phone owner must accept to install the app outside google play, the phone will warn him its not safe, i dont know if he will trust you installing unsigned package into his phone personally i wouldn't ask him to install my app ill bring a test device  with the app installed
in it and give him the device  to try the app, there's some legal risks there if you asks someone to install your app outside google play, thats why i wouldn't ask some to install my app even its safe, you should only install signed apps from google play for safety but for testing purposes android  allows side loading while ios does not allow that

Comment: So what should I do to show my app to interviewer , can I use expo?

Comment: Isthe interview going to be in person or remotely?

Comment: Interview would be online

Comment: In that case sharing your screen will be enough i accept that when i interview someone or if im beinginterviewedi offer sharingmy screenand explain my code, open your android virtual device and show him, and offer him the APK file if he want to download it to his phone, good luck